# JavaScript logic problem with dynamically deleting component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, dynamic

I am mapping values from an array to create a < select> dropdown. I want to be able to dynamically create and delete them. I have figured out creation (using mapping) but I have an issue with deletion. I'm using a key in the array to differentiate values but my problem is that when I go to delete a specific < select>, only the newest created  gets deleted. This is because the key being passed into the delete method is the newest key create (line 2: let key = array.key;). What is a workaround solution that will let me pass the correct key into the delete method while keeping line 2. Hopefully this makes sense. Thanks

EDIT: The solution below works just make sure to update the components you are mapping in the state or the old array will be used to map

```
{this.state.AdditionQueryArray.map((array) => {
          let key = array.key;
          return (
            <div>
              <Select
                onChange={(e) => this.HandleChange(e, key)}
                options={this.state.OperatorOptions}
                placeholder="Select Operator"
                menuPortalTarget={document.body}
                menuPosition={"fixed"}
              />
              <button onClick={() => this.delete(key)}>Delete</button>
              <div> 
            )
      }


delete(key) {
    const state = this.state;
    for (var i = state.AdditionQueryArray.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
      if (state.AdditionQueryArray[i].key == key) {
        state.AdditionQueryArray.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
    this.setState(state);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why wouldn't you pass the index instead of key?

If you're using index, you can exclude it with filter. As Example

```
{this.state.AdditionQueryArray.map((array, index) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <Select
                onChange={(e) => this.HandleChange(e, key)}
                options={this.state.OperatorOptions}
                placeholder="Select Operator"
                menuPortalTarget={document.body}
                menuPosition={"fixed"}
              />
              <button onClick={() => this.delete(index)}>Delete</button>
              <div> 
            )
      }


delete(index) {
let tempArray = [...this.state.AdditionQueryArray]
let filteredArray = tempArray.filter((item, arrayIndex) => arrayIndex !== index)
this.setState({
    AdditionQueryArray: filteredArray
})
```

I usually use this when I want to delete an element of list. I also add `[...array]` to make it didn't edit state directly

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I have a follow up. This is the structure of my array. 
 AdditionQueryArray: [{key: "key", operator: "and/or", field: "field", property: "property", PropValue:"Propvalue", }].  With your current code I'm getting the error : this.state.additionQueryArray is not iterable. Do you know the fix? Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I have typo in copying your array. It should be this.state.AdditionQueryArray not this.state.additionQueryArray in delete function

Answer (score 1):

easiest way might be adding custom(data) attribute to that `button` tag and set it to `key` and read that attribute with `event` object in `delete` function

check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes